# Can you reorder divs with only CSS and keep them inline like a paragraph? (no display flex or grid)

Tags: css

I have three divs elements, all containing text and nested inside another div, which I all want to be inline like a paragraph, and I can't change the HTML or use JS. The 2nd div can have text longer than one line, and I want to be last in the div order, and for the 3rd div to be 1st. The divs can have any font size and any content (but the 1st and 3rd one will always be only 1 character, but can be any character), I want to achieve this without applying properties with specific measurements like `20px` or whatnot.

I tried `order` with `display: flex` and `grid` but elements can't be inline like a paragraph with them. `order` doesn't work with `inline-flex` either.

Sample HTML:

```css
body > div {
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #FFF;
}

div div {
    display: inline;
  padding: 0 5px
}

div div:first-child {
    background: blue;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
    background: green;
}

div:nth-child(3) {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div>t</div>
<div>text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
<div>t</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you can't use flex or grid, so that `order` would work, then there isn't too much else you can do. Positioning anything absolutely to "rearrange" the flow will rather be out of the question with dynamic texts as well, I suppose.

Comment: @CBroe the problem is not that the OP can not use flex or grid (he actually can). The problem is that flex and grid have no "paragraph of text" concept and thus do not wrap lines.

Comment: @RobertSiemer that's a bit nit-picky, isn't it? If it doesn't give the desired _result_, then that falls under "can't use" for me as well.

Comment: @CBroe I just wanted to stress that a solution is not restricted that way. Maybe there is a possibility with flex/grid... if not now, maybe in the future...

Comment: Please don't make edits that invalidate or change what OP is asking or their circumstances. In this case, OP says they have three divs and that HTML 'cannot be changed'. Any edit by another user that changes their HTML is thus invalid/not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of changing the source order is somewhat newish in CSS. Flex and grid layout picked this idea up, but the old standard flow layout does not have that feature.

As dynamic line-breaks are a feature of flow layout, I guess you are out of luck.